# Sitecore 9 Forms designer error

Tags: sitecore-forms

When I click on Forms icon from Launchpad in Sitecore 9, i am getting the error below:

1. I tried rebuilding the master index
2. Compare Core database dashboard with other environments - no difference i could see
3. Checked the logs which is having the same information

Please advise me what went wrong here

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: innerItem
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: innerItem

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: innerItem]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +64
   Sitecore.Mvc.HtmlExtensions.RenderView(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String renderingItemId, Object parameters) +122
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Forms_FormPanels_Form_cshtml.Execute() +2576
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Forms/FormPanels/Form.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Forms.FormPanels.FormRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Containers_Borders_Border_cshtml.Execute() +1499
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Containers/Borders/Border.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Containers.Borders.BorderRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Containers_Borders_ProgressIndicatorPanel_cshtml.Execute() +897
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Containers/Borders/ProgressIndicatorPanel.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Containers.Borders.ProgressIndicatorPanelRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Dialogs_DialogWindows_DialogWindow_cshtml.Execute() +3332
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Dialogs/DialogWindows/DialogWindow.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Dialogs.DialogWindows.DialogWindowRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Containers_Borders_Border_cshtml.Execute() +1499
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Containers/Borders/Border.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Containers.Borders.BorderRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action) +196
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter output, Item item) +270
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +143
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +126
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ControlsExtension.ItemRenderer(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, Boolean useItemAsDataSource) +133
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_version_2_Layouts_Renderings_Containers_SubAppRenderers_SubAppRenderer_cshtml.Execute() +723
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Containers/SubAppRenderers/SubAppRenderer.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Containers.SubAppRenderers.SubAppRendererRenderingModel, Sitecore.Speak.Components').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_FlexLayout_cshtml.Execute() +1114
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-FlexLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
```

Comment: When you open developer tools - Network tab do you see any 500 errors?

Comment: yes. Page status code is 500. No other xhr request shown

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue within Sitecore(9.3) forms.

I was building a custom save action and at somepoint, I have faced this same error.

Here is what I did.

I have created a custom save action here : `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/Actions/ACustomSaveAction`

Within this Custom Save action Item, I have multiple items such as :

- HeaderSubtitle
- HeaderTitle

Then, I needed an itemTreeView (just like the *Redirect to page* save action). So I created one by duplicated it, added it to my custom save action's control (from presentation details).

The catch was, I had put this item within another item(of type `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Containers/Expander/Expander Parameter`), by trying to create a section with a name. Long story short, anytime this itemTreeView(  `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Lists and Grids/ItemTreeView/ItemTreeView Parameters`) item was under an item, I got this error. Just had to move this item as a direct child of `PageSettings` and I was good to go.

My first thoughts were code related, turns out it wasnt. Hope it helps ..!